# Proving that, if $\forall X\in \mathbb R^n, ||g(X)||\leq M||X||^2$, then $\forall X \in \mathbb R^n, Df(0)(X)=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm having some trouble with the following question:

> Let $g:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ be a function of class $C^1$ and assume that there exists an $M>0$ such that :$$\forall X\in \mathbb R^n, ||g(X)||\leq M||X||^2$$
> Prove that $\forall X \in \mathbb R^n, Dg(0)(X)=0$

I remember that when I was having real analysis I proved that if $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a function such that $\forall x \in \mathbb R,|g(x)|<M|x|^2$ for some $M>0$, then $g'(0)=0$. I read my old proof and tried to generalize it but failed. I tried the following:

If $\forall X \in \mathbb R^n, Dg(0)(X)=0$, then this means that the jacobian matrix of $g$ at $0$ is the zero matrix, and in particular: For all $i,j\in \{1,...,n\}:$ $$\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial e_j}(0)=0$$

And I tried to compute this using the limit definition of the partial derivative and tried to use the inequality $||g(X)||\leq M||X||^2$ to prove that the derivative is zero. I couldn't do this because I wasn't capable of extracting any useful information about each component $g_i$ from that inequality.

How can this be proven?

Comment: I would suggest using the actual definition of the derivative as a linear map, although you can of course do the partial derivatives. Note, of course, that  $|g_i(X)|\le \|g(X)\|$. (By the way, the partial derivative $\partial g/\partial x_i(0)$ makes sense as a vector.)

Comment: I also tried using the definition of derivative as a linear map but failed. That's why I tried doing it with partial derivatives. How would you do it with the definition of derivative as a linear map? @TedShifrin

Comment: Use uniqueness. Show that the $0$-map satisfies the limit definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\|g(0)\|\leqslant M\|0\|^2=0$. And $Dg(0)$ is such that$$\lim_{X\to 0}\frac{\|g(X)-g(0)-Dg(0)(X)\|}{\|X\|}=0,$$which means that$$\lim_{X\to 0}\frac{\|g(X)-Dg(0)(X)\|}{\|X\|}=0.$$But $\frac{\|g(X)\|}{\|X\|}\leqslant M\|X\|$, and therefore$$\lim_{X\to 0}\frac{\|g(X)\|}{\|X\|}=0.$$So, $Dg(0)$ is the null function.